# How can I get values that looks like a JSON dict in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Here's the thing, I have a table looking like this:

```
col1        col2                                     col3
A           {"0":10, "5":5, "15":3}                  6
B           {"5":30, "10":20, "15":10, "20":5}       15
C           {"0":30, "3":20, "8":10, "9":5}          2
.
.
.
```

col2 is basically a rank (number between quotes) and a grade; col3 is the rank for each customer (defined in col1). So if the customer A is ranked 0-4, his grade is 10, if he's ranked 5-14, his grade is 5, otherwise is 3.
I need to create a new column by getting the grade corresponding to the rank defined in col3.

This is what the final result would look like:

```
col1        col2                                     col3    col4
A           {"0":10, "5":5, "15":3}                  5       5
B           {"5":30, "10":20, "15":10, "20":5}       13      20
C           {"0":30, "3":20, "8":10, "9":5}          2       30
.
.
.
```

Any ideas? I thought about split_part(), but I don't think I can make this work, even by putting many case when (not sure, couldn't think of a solution).

Answer (score 0):

You may find the below approach useful.
Unfortunately, Redshift has less amount of needed functions comparing to PostgreSQL (which it is based on).
That's why I had to apply some workaround - table "number_sequence", which is used to extract grades from customer JSONs. It is necessary to populate this table with sequential numbers up to the value of maximum rank, presented in customer JSON dictionaries. Also, since I dont have access to Redshift I have tested the solution only in PostgreSQL. So it might be nessecary to made some tailoring to Redshift environment. Have a good luck! :)

```
CREATE TABLE number_sequence (
    num int
);

INSERT INTO number_sequence (num)
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
  (0),  (1),  (2),  (3),  (4),  (5),  (6),  (7),  (8),  (9),
  (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19),
  (20), (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29)
) num_sec;

CREATE TABLE customer_rank_grade (
  col1 varchar,
  col2 varchar,
  col3 int
);

INSERT INTO customer_rank_grade (col1, col2, col3)
select * from
(values 
('A', '{"0":10, "5":5, "15":3}',            5),
('B', '{"5":30, "10":20, "15":10, "20":5}', 13),
('C', '{"0":30, "3":20, "8":10, "9":5}',    2)
) data;

WITH selected_rank as (
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  json_extract_path_text(col2::json, num::varchar) as col4,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY num DESC) as row_num
FROM number_sequence
JOIN customer_rank_grade
  ON json_extract_path_text(col2::json, num::varchar) IS NOT NULL
WHERE num <= col3
)
SELECT 
  col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM selected_rank
WHERE row_num = 1
ORDER BY col1;
```